# Ephemeral Concourse Web Servers

Tags: concourse

Our organization has decided the concourse servers should be ephemeral / phoenix servers.  Is this a best practice?

I've seen a number issues with this.  One is that all of my CI builds run again when the pipelines are recreated because it doesn't know that it's already seen that resource version.  Is this something that is trivial to work around or does the speak to the heart of the first question?

Comment: I don't know anyone that is using ephemeral servers for concourse. In theory, it should work, but in practice since CI/CD is a vital component, it's nice not to have to go down in the middle of a build.

Comment: Each dev team is being told to create their own 60 day temp server.  After 60 days it's destroyed and we have to create another one and reload our pipelines.  Thoughts?

Comment: What's the goal of doing that?

Comment: I imagine the thought was to create a developer self service model of provisioning the CI system without having to standup and maintain a centralized system with all the red tape associated with it. There is also a "free" (funny money) internal service that builds disposable servers where gettin a proper server costs $$$$ (funny money).  I personally think we should have one maintained system with one concourse team per github enterprise org.  But I understand teams don't prevent bad actors.  Some people also spouted about how bad snow flake servers are and for the workers I agree.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to worry about bad actors. Concourse is expressly designed to prevent servers from ever becoming snowflakes, as all of your configuration _has to_ be stored in code that you can then keep in source control. As long as you keep your pipeline config files in source control you will never end up with a snowflaky server. If all the VMs disappeared tomorrow, you could spin up the exact same Concourse right away with no problem, but the reason we don't recommend burning down your whole installation is that it will negatively impact the performance of your Concourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concourse is meant to be a long running application and needs to be running for some time for the caches to warm up, etc. It will work, but it is not considered a best practice, and you will certainly take a performance hit if you take this approach. The performance implications are something you will have to weigh against the other benefits of using ephemeral servers.

If you are recreating your Concourse from scratch, you are definitely going to see your builds retrigger, and this is by design. If you have to use the phoenix server approach, your best bet is to cheat by snapshotting your database before burning it down. Use that snapshot to create the new database server, and you will preserve your build history and prevent builds from retriggering unnecessarily.

Comment: So if I ran my PostgreSQL outside of docker and kept it persisted but kept my web ephemeral I'd see performance hits but not triggered builds?  I suppose I could live with that.

Comment: That's right. You will need your database to persist to prevent the builds triggering.